# Google Map API JS - interference between two on one page?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with several different views. At the top there is a small gogole map for searching. One of the views has a results map.
Site done in MVC 5 bootstrap 4.

Both were working together but as you do was adding/changing things. Now they don't play well together.

When the results map is shown - the smaller search map does not display the roadmap. Map seems to have initialised ok - but doesn't show the roads/map. If I change to Satellite - it seems to show within part of the map/frame only. I've also noticed that the MapType control has changed from a bar to a drop-down, which is the default for smaller screens.

As far as I can see - bot maps use separate variables.
Won't post the code here initially as there's a fair bit - and I thought I'd make a preliminary query in case someone has experienced such behaviour before.
If I disable the results map the search map works again.

Correct search map, when shown on a page/view without second map :
[image: search map showing ok]

On page/view where the second map is displayed. Note change of map type control:
[image: roads not showing, map type control changed]

If I change to display Satellite rather than road - a portion displays. This is drageable to a certain extent but portion will then change:
[image: Satellite showing to a certain extent]

Any ideas ?
Could bootstrap be sending incorrect screen size signals ?
Can post the code if think it will help.

To clarify:

- MVC = ASP.Net MVC
- Bootstrap = http://getbootstrap.com v 3.3.4

Search Map definition.
Note HTML and JS contains some ASP.Net MVC Razor code prefixed with "@"
Also the map is only initialised when the Bootstrap panel is opened not on window load.

```js
< script >


  var markersSearch = [];
var mapSearch;



function ClearSearch() {
  //clear values + submmit form empty

  var form = document.getElementById("searchform");

  document.getElementById("Search").value = "";
  document.getElementById("eventtypeID").selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("EventFrom").value = "";
  document.getElementById("EventTo").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Free").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("hidLat").value = "";
  document.getElementById("hidLng").value = "";
  document.getElementById("distance").selectedIndex = 1;

  ClearLocations();

  form.submit();
}


function showsearch() {
  //show serch panel
  //only initialise map if not already done
  if (typeof mapSearch == 'undefined') {
    initializeSearch();
  }
}


function SetMyLocation() {




  //clear existing markers
  ClearLocations();
  //set to current pos

  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      mapSearch.setCenter(initialLocation);


      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapSearch,
        //icon: image,
        title: 'My Location',
        position: initialLocation,
        draggable: true
      });

      //display
      markersSearch.push(marker);

      //zoom
      mapSearch.setZoom(16);

      //listener
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(event) {
        SetHtmlLocation(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
        SeHtmltLocation(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
      });

      SetHtmlLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    });
  }

}

function SetLocation(lat, lng) {

    ClearLocations();
    var setLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // Create a marker for each place.
    var markerSetLoc = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapSearch,
      //icon: image,
      title: 'My Location',
      position: setLocation,
      draggable: true
    });


    mapSearch.setCenter(setLocation);

    //zoom
    mapSearch.setZoom(16);

    //listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerSetLoc, 'drag', function(event) {
      SetHtmlLocation(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerSetLoc, 'dragend', function(event) {
      SetHtmlLocation(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
    });


    //addd to array
    markersSearch.push(markerSetLoc);

    SetHtmlLocation(lat, lng);


  } //SetLocation

function SetHtmlLocation(lat, lng) {
  document.getElementById("hidLat").value = lat;
  document.getElementById("hidLng").value = lng;
}


function ClearLocationsIncInput() {
  document.getElementById("pac-input").value = '';
  ClearLocations();
}

function ClearLocations() {

  for (var i = 0; i < markersSearch.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(markersSearch[i]);
    markersSearch[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersSearch = [];

  SetHtmlLocation(null, null);

}

function initializeSearch() {


    //initialise starting point if form re-submited
    @
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.currentLat)) {@: var londonLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(@ViewBag.currentLat, @ViewBag.currentLng);@: var zoom = 16;
      //SetHtmlLocation done in control itself
    } else {@: var londonLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507, -0.1277);@: var zoom = 13;
    }



    var mapOptionsSearch = {
      center: londonLatLong,
      zoom: zoom,
      streetViewControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };




    mapSearch = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('event-map-search'), mapOptionsSearch);



    //IF ORIGINALLY PLACED - set marker on postback
    @
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.currentLat)) {

      @: SetLocation(@ViewBag.currentLat, @ViewBag.currentLng);

    }



    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = /** @@type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));

    var inputgroup = (document.getElementById('pac-input-group'));

    //mapSearch.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    mapSearch.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(inputgroup);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox( /** @@type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));


    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {


      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }
      for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markersSearch[i]; i++) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }

      // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
      ClearLocations();



      //use places[0]
      SetLocation(places[0].geometry.location.lat(), places[0].geometry.location.lng());


    });
    // [END region_getplaces]

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
    // current map's viewport.
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapSearch, 'bounds_changed', function() {
      var boundsBias = mapSearch.getBounds();
      searchBox.setBounds(boundsBias);
    });


    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  } //initialize




$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})







< /script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css"> #event-map-search {

  height: 100%;

  width: 100%;

  min-width: 200px;

  min-height: 200px;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

.controls {

  margin-top: 16px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;

  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;

  box-sizing: border-box;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 32px;

  outline: none;

  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

/*Auto complete ?*/

#type-selector {

  color: #fff;

  background-color: #4d90fe;

  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;

}

#type-selector label {

  /*font-family: Roboto;*/

  font-size: 13px;

  font-weight: 300;

}

#pac-input {

  background-color: #fff;

  /*font-family: Roboto;*/

  /*font-size: 10px;*/

  font-weight: 300;

  width: 280px;

  /*padding: 0 11px 0 13px;*/

  text-overflow: ellipsis;

}

#pac-input-group {

  width: 300px;

  margin-top: 6px;

  margin-left: 6px;

}

#pac-input:focus {

  border-color: #4d90fe;

}

/*TODO - move to CSS*/

</style>
```

```html
<div id="pac-input-group" class="input-group">
  <input id="pac-input" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Choose a location">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Set to my location" onclick="javascript: SetMyLocation();">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Clear Location" onclick="javascript: ClearLocationsIncInput();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="event-map-search"></div>
@Html.Hidden("hidLat", (object)ViewBag.currentLat) @Html.Hidden("hidLng", (object)ViewBag.currentLng)
```

Code for the Display map, in one view which is included as a Razor/MVC:

```
Html.RenderPartial("EventsMap", Model);
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  var markersDisplay = [];
var mapDisplay;
var boundsDisplay = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initializeDisplayMap() {



  @
  if (Model.Count > 0) {@: var firstPointDisplay = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.FirstOrDefault().address_latitude, @Model.FirstOrDefault().address_longitude);
  } else {@: var firstPointDisplay = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507, -0.1277);
  }




  var mapOptionsDisplay = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: firstPointDisplay,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  mapDisplay = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('event-map-display'), mapOptionsDisplay);

  //draw marker code from C#
  @
  foreach(var item in Model) {@: addMarkerDisplay(@item.address_latitude, @item.address_longitude, '@Html.EncodeJsString(item.event_title)', @item.event_ID);

  }

  //collect all in bounds

  for (i = 0; i < markersDisplay.length; i++) {
    boundsDisplay.extend(markersDisplay[i].getPosition());
  }
  //bounds map
  mapDisplay.fitBounds(boundsDisplay);
}


function addMarkerDisplay(x, y, ptitle, eID) {

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
  var newmarkerDisplay = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: ptitle,
    map: mapDisplay,
    draggable: false,
    id: eID
  });

  markersDisplay.push(newmarkerDisplay);

  google.maps.event.addListener(newmarkerDisplay, 'click', function() {
    highlightevent(this.id);
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeDisplayMap);



function highlightevent(id) {



  $('#eventMapTable tr').each(function() {
    //alert($(this).data('id'));
    $(this).removeClass("eventMapRowHighlight");
    if ($(this).data('id') == id) {
      $(this).addClass("eventMapRowHighlight");
    }
  });


}

< /script>
```

```css
/*---------------Events--------------------------*/

#event-map-display {

  height: 100%;

  width: 100%;

  min-width: 300px;

  min-height: 500px;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

.eventTable tbody tr:hover td {

  background-color: black;

  color: white;

}

.eventTable tbody tr {

  cursor: pointer;

}

#EventListImageContainer {

  padding-top: 5px;

  height: 100%;

}

#EventMapContainer {

  padding-top: 5px;

  height: 100%;

}

#EventListImageContainer img {

  display: block;

  margin-left: auto;

  margin-right: auto;

}

.eventMapRowHighlight {

  background-color: @highlightcol1;

-webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;

  -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;

  -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;

  -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;

  transition: background 0.5s linear;

}
```

```html
<div id="EventMapContainer" class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
  <div id="event-map-display"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For people to help you, you need to cut down your code to a working example so others can test and replicate it. jsfiddle is good for this. This way people can also test a potential fix and confirm the problem as solved. People are not so likely to guess at the answer in speculation.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "MVC 5" and "bootstrap 4" please? MVC what? bootstrap 4.0 (in which case, where to find it) or 3.3.4?

Comment: Where is your code? We can't tell anything without code.

Comment: Code added to the original post.

As added there MVC 5 = ASP.Net MVC 5 using Razor notation within HTML and JavaScript code.
Bootstrap = 3.3.4 (sorry not 4)

Comment: Additional point of interest.

When I run code to find Lat/Longitude via HTML 5 Geo-location, draw the marker and set map to centre on it - it doesn't do it - the point is somewhat outside the frame of view. As if the map initialised is off where it think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. :)

Was calling the faulty map initialise routine from a onclick of the button that opened the Boostrap panel where it was located.
This had been working and still did when the page did not contain another map.

Thought I'd check for events fired after the boostrap panel had finished opening as it seemed to be a peculiarity to do with sizing.

So instead of firing on the button onclick I implemented the bootstrap event "shown.bs.collapse" : This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Thus:

```js
    $('#searchpanel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    if (typeof mapSearch == 'undefined') {
        initializeSearch();
        }
    })
```